# Will UK DLC work on a zone 4 game for PS4?

Tags: ps4

A while ago I bought Fallout 4 for the PS4 on Amazon which turned out to be shipped from Australia to the UK and a region 4 game. A little surprised but I went with it. My question is will a DLC pack bought in the UK work on the region 4 game?

Comment: For reference: the reason I've removed the fallout tag is because 1) It refers to the original game on PC and 2) Since FO4 has not released any DLC yet, it's considered off topic to discuss it's future DLC. So it's fine to mention, but best left out of the direct question just to be safe.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

DLC has to be from the same region as the Game.
DLC is usually region locked to the game even if the games themselves are not.
So you can play with your Australian Game with Australian DLC on your UK PS4.

But to play with DLC you will have to purchase DLC from the Australian store to use it with your game.

Comment: Thanks for the help, any idea how i go about buying dlc from Australia?

Comment: @Carlos You will have to create a new account with the region you want (Australia). And use it to purchase from the Australian PSN store. You will need a PSN card from that region that you can buy online. All the stuff you buy with it and downloaded will be usable on your normal PSN user account.

Comment: If i buy the season pass from the psn in the uk while using a region 4 game it wont work?

Comment: Depends on what region the store actually is. And that depends on the User account on your PS4, not the game.

Comment: Ok how about this. Would it be possible to use an Australian season pass on my UK account which has been running the region 4 game?

Comment: Yes, The DLC has to match the game. The region of your account doesn't matter, what matters is that game and DLC both have the same region.